# Runtime error with python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am working on min steps problem. I have alternate solution but want to understand where I am going wrong.

> Problem: You are in an infinite 2D grid where you can move in any of
>   the 8 directions:
>
> (x,y) to  (x+1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1),  (x-1, y-1),
>   (x+1,y+1), (x-1,y+1), (x+1,y-1).   You are given a sequence of points
>   and the order in  which you need to cover the points. Give the minimum
>   number  of steps in which you can achieve it. You start from the first
>   point.
>   Input : [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)] 
>    Output : 2

I tried the following approach where X represents x coordinates and Y represents Y coordinates. I am seeing it is failing for the following input. The expected output is 108 and I am getting 118. The difference of y coordinates is coming as 19,5,7,10,25,4,11,2

> X : [ 4, 8, -7, -5, -13, 9, -7, 8 ] Y : [ 4, -15, -10, -3, -13, 12, 8,
>   -8 ]

I observed it is failing in last two iterations. I tried printing y coordinates difference and found 11 and 2 are coming and not understanding why they are coming. Any help is greatly needed. Thanks in Advance.

```
 def coverPoints(self, X, Y):
        count=0
        if(len(X)<=1):
            return 0
        for (a,b) in zip(X,Y):
            ind = X.index(a)
            if(len(X)==ind+1):
                break
            m=X[ind+1]-a
            n=Y[ind+1]-b
            if(m<0):
                m=-m
            if(n<0):
                n=-n
            if(m<=n):
                print(n)
                count=count+n
            else:
                print(n)
                count=count+m

        return count
```

Comment: It'll be better to create a self sufficient description of the problem without providing an external link

Comment: `ind = X.index(a)` will return the index of the _first_ occurence of `a`. Use `for ind,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(X,Y)):` instead.

Comment: Thanks Rawing. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Rawing's answer helped. Here is the solution with modification.

```
def coverPoints(self, X, Y):
        count=0
        if(len(X)<=1):
            return 0
        for ind,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(X,Y)):
            if(len(X)==ind+1):
                break
            m=X[ind+1]-a
            n=Y[ind+1]-b
            if(m<0):
                m=-m
            if(n<0):
                n=-n
            if(m<=n):
                count=count+n
            else:
                count=count+m

        return count
```